# Navigation controller moves all views down by 64px in Storyboard despite it being hidden.

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7.1

In the View Controller, I set the navigation bar so that

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

However, I am running into the issue that whichever way my `UIViews` are laid out in `Storyboard`, all the `UIViews` at runtime are moved down 64px. Is there a way that I could set so that both the NavBar is hidden, and that it does not affect how the `UIViews` are laid out on screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually , I use this to hide navigationBar.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

While,

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Is the property for UIView, this is a method for `UINavigationController`.